# Using iterator_traits to deduce value type from pair of iterators

Tags: c++11, iterator-traits

I have a type

```
typedef std::pair<ConstIterator, ConstIterator> Range;
```

with

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator ConstIterator;
```

I would now like to use std::iterator_traits to deduce the type the iterators of a Range are pointing to.

Could anybody please tell me how I can achieve this, from an object of type Range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a type trait, partially specialized on a `pair`:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_type {
    using type = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct value_type<std::pair<T, T>>
: value_type<T>
{ };
```

Comment: Why not directly add the specialization to `std::iterator_traits` ?

Comment: @Quentin You can only add specializations for user-defined types. Neither the `pair` nor its constituents in the example are user-defined types.

Comment: Oh. I went ahead of myself then.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for your answer. One question, if I want to declare a variable of the type the iterators of the Range are pointing to, how would I do this using your approach? I tried value_type<Range>::type myVar; but I get an error "error: expected ';' after expression value_type<Range>::type myVar = {};"

Comment: @1v0 Can't tell. Possibly missing `typename`, definitely don't need the `=`. Just `typename value_type<Range>::type var{};` should be fine. Could add an alias so that you could do `value_type_t<Range> var{};`

Comment: @Barry, i tried to add the typename but then I get this really weird error: "no type named 'value_type' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<double>'"

Answer (score 0):

This will support both your `pair` based ranges, and most iterables:

```
template<class R>
struct value_type {
  using iterator_type = decltype( std::begin(std::declval<R>()) );
  using type=typename std::iterator_traits<iterator_type>::value_type;
};
template<class It>
struct value_type<std::pair<It,It>> {
  using type=typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
};
template<class X>
using value_t = typename value_type<X>::type;
```

note that the value type of a const iterator is a non-const value.

The above is not SFINAE friendly -- an industrial quality one would be.

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly allowed to add template specializations to the `std` namespace for user-defined types (thanks Barry for the precision !). If you rework your `Range` to be an actual type (not just a typedef), you can do this :

```
struct Range : std::pair<ConstIterator, ConstIterator> {
    using std::pair<ConstIterator, ConstIterator>::pair;
};

namespace std {
    template <>
    struct iterator_traits<Range> : iterator_traits<ConstIterator> {};
}
```

When you buff your `Range` a bit, I expect this to evolve into :

```
namespace std {
    template <class T>
    struct iterator_traits<Range<T>> : iterator_traits<T> {};
}
```